# Installing older version of postgres using homebrew

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I am trying to use an older version of postgres and I cannot get it to work.  When I run `brew search postgres` I see:

```
$ brew search postgresql
==> Searching local taps...
postgresql ✔         postgresql@9.4 ✔      postgresql@9.5          postgresql@9.6
```

but then when I run `brew switch postgres 9.4` I see:

```
$ brew switch postgresql 9.4
Error: postgresql does not have a version "9.4" in the Cellar.
Versions available: 9.6.2, 9.6.4
```

What am I missing?  I need to run version 9.4

Comment: You need to `brew install postgresql@9.4` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brew switch` works only on installed versions of a specific formula. You have `postgresql` versions `9.6.2` and `9.6.4` on your machine, so you can only `switch` to one of those.

However Homebrew provides fixed-version formulae using the `<name>@<version>` thing. In order to get Postgres 9.4, you can run the following command:

```
brew install postgresql@9.4
```